# Nittel Nacht in Israel

Tags: torah-study, rabbis, non-jewish-holidays

Do Gedolim in Israel not learn on Nittel Nacht? The [Nitei Gavriel (3:1)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=397) writes

> בארץ ישראל יש אומרים שאין לחוש לניטל אכן רוב הגדולים חשו לזה גם בא"י
> -- Some say it doesn't apply in Israel, but most Gedolim are still concerned for Nittel Nacht.

It just doesn't seem like Rav Chaim Kanievsky and most other Gedolei Yisroel don't learn then...

Comment: I think the practice of not learning on that night is almost exclusively a Hasidic one nowadays. So I assume by "most Gedolim" he's referring specifically to Hasidic Gedolim. The Gedolim of the Lithuanian tradition learn on that night, even outside Israel.

Comment: He gives two names as examples; you give one name. How do you want to evaluate which side has the most gedolim on it? Are you just looking for more examples?

Comment: Isn't "minhag hamakom" of Israeli Christians Greek Orthodox?

Comment: @Heshy it's more complicated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_Quo_(Jerusalem_and_Bethlehem)

Comment: איו למדים ממנהגי עמי הארץ. At least three meanings.